# Pass a pointer to a class function in c++

Tags: c++, class, pointers

I am learning classes in c++ so I try different things to get used to the classes. Here I am trying to pass a pointer to a class function:

```
class Pointerss{
    int size;
public:
    Pointerss(int);
    void f();
    int *a;
};

Pointerss::Pointerss(int siz){
    size = siz;
}

void Pointerss::f(){
    cout<<"Size is:"<<size<<"\n";
    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
       cout<<"a is:"<<a[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
int main() {
    int size = 5;
    Pointerss dd (size);
    Pointerss * p = new Pointerss(size);
    p[0]=1; p[1]=2; p[2]=3; p[3]=4; p[4]=5;
    p->a;
    dd.f();
    return 0;

}
```

So the "size" is initialized by a constructor and when "f()" is called the correct digit is printed. But when I assign "p" to "a" ("p->a") and then call "f()" some random numbers are printed. My computer prints :

```
Size is:5
a is:0
a is:0
a is:1
a is:0
a is:1606416856
Program ended with exit code: 0
```

what is the difference between "a" and "size" and what should I do to pass a pointer to a function?

Comment: I can see at least 3 different questions.

Comment: This is going to be closed and deleted, but you need to read a beginner [C++ book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/96780) that teaches you what "p->a" is (certainly, not an assignment) and how to do variable initializations and assignments.

Comment: `Pointerss* p = new Pointerss(size)` allocates a single element, not an array. so `p[1]=2` is out of bound access and so is UB.

Comment: There is also a good tutorial here: http://www.cplusplus.com/doc/tutorial/

Answer (score 1):

Random numbers are printed because `Pointerss::f` dereferences `dd.a` which you never initialized. Dereferencing an uninitialized pointer results in undefined behaviour.

That's not the only bug you have. You also allocate memory for a single `Pointerss` object, which is pointed by `p`, but then proceed to construct objects in `p[1..4]` which point to unallocated memory. That also results in undefined behaviour.

Thirdly, you never deallocate the memory that you allocated with `new`.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1 would be to understand pointers. When you make a `int*` you only reserve memory to store the pointer itself. You don't reserve memory for any `int`. So when you try to print the integers you just get random numbers (or perhaps a program crash).

So your class can't hold any integers. You need to change it so that you reserve memory in the constructor and release it in the destructor.

```
class Pointerss{
    int size;
public:
    Pointerss(int);
    ~Pointerss();
    void f();
    int *a;
};

Pointerss::Pointerss(int siz){
    size = siz;
    a = new int[size];  // Reserve memory for size integers

    // Do some initialization if needed, e.g.
    for (int i=0; i < size; i++) a[i] = i;
}

Pointerss::~Pointerss(){
    delete[] a;         // Release the memory again
}

void Pointerss::f(){
    cout<<"Size is:"<<size<<"\n";
    for (int i=0; i<size; ++i) {
       cout<<"a is:"<<a[i]<<"\n";
    }
}
```

Further you can't make a single pointer to an instance of the class, i.e.

```
Pointerss * p = new Pointerss(size);
```

and then use it like

```
p[0]=1; p[1]=2; p[2]=3; p[3]=4; p[4]=5;
```

because that is operating on 5 different instances.

Finally the code:

```
p->a;
```

does nothing!

You could do

```
p->a[0] = 5;
```

but it is unclear what you are trying to do.

Notice that dd and p are refering to two different instances of your class so changing something inside `*p` doesn't change dd at all.

If you had done:

```
Pointerss *p = &dd;
```

then `*p` and dd would be the same instance.